# Changing a Dimmer to Single Pole with Three Black and Three White Wires

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have done basic electrical work in my house. I am trying to replace a dimmer with a single pole switch. The setup, as I know it, is this dimmer controls the fan and light. Why the previous owners did this is beyond me. It actually hummed when turned on and if the dimmer was adjusted it would hum oddly. It never felt safe to me.

I figured this was going to be simple, but once I opened the the switch up to expose the wiring I became confused.

[image: Dimmer Switch Crazy]

It is unclear to me how this should map on to a single pole switch. I don't believe this is a three-way as I've never seen it control more than just the fan/light. Perhaps I could control the fan from the light, but I installed the fan several months ago and don't recall that kind of wiring there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Pigtail the 2 blacks going to 1 side of the switch to 1 side of the new switch, remove the red wire and connect that black to the other side of the switch,  it is a metal box if metal with the ground screwed to the box mount the switch and you will be good to go.